# tell a program to not use the VPN

Tags: windows-7, windows, vpn, routing

is it possible to tell a program like chrome to not use the VPN connection while i am connected to VPN for other programs?

otherwise is it possibile to tell only some programs to use the VPN and the others use the normal internet connection?

i'm using a VPN created on windows server 2012 and the basic windows VPN connection

thank you

Comment: It depends on what you need vpn for. You can make vpn being used for things when its not available through the normal means (local network / internet) which is not enabled by default. But if you want to use the VPN for something that is available on the internet too, there's no way to selectively use VPN or not. Can you answer this question? Does the part you need to connect to with VPN also be accessible without VPN?

Comment: the university internet blocks all games ect, so that's why i have the vpn for.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, do the following:

1. Open the properties of your VPN connection.
2. Go to the tab Networking.
3. Doubleclick the Internet Protocol Version 4 (TCP/IPv4) from the list.
4. Click <kbd>Advanced...</kbd>
5. Uncheck `Use default gateway on remote network`.
6. Click OK a few times until all dialogs are closed.

Now, all traffic remains to go through your normal lan connection unless it cannot reach its destination. In that case it will try the VPN connection.

Comment: trying that, but steam and battlefield 3 don't work. they just don't connect(i.e using normal university connection)

Comment: That means the university doesn't block all ports, but only some. An initial connection is being made, but additional connections are blocked. That means you can't use this method then. Either all VPN or not.